# Printing text to look chatroom-like?

Tags: python

I would like to write a script that reads some input from the user and then prints a statement in a way that feels chatroom-like: letters appear one after the other, there is a blinking cursor at the current position, and some random believable delay between characters. Preferably in python, but really any language that you think is most appropriate. I am thinking that this is doable with manim, but wondering if there are any existing solutions out there.

Here is an example of how it should look like (the third line. This is ***ChatGPT***)

[image: Example of chatroom-like printing]

Comment: Given that the question even mentions programming language (Python), I think Stack Overflow is probably a better place for this. Check this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608275/how-can-i-print-text-so-it-looks-like-its-being-typed-out

Comment: Also, it's relevant where this will be displayed. If it's for a web page, you should be able to do it with CSS https://blog.hubspot.com/website/typing-animation-css

Comment: Thank you both, I consider this solved since the other answer you linked to is very relevant. When I find the time I'll post the script, adding the blinking cursor